# How do I know who creates a blob if uploading through SAS?

Tags: android, azure, blob

I upload an image to Azure Blob storage through use of SAS from my android device. I'm trying to trace the creator of a blob in Windows Azure, but the Blob storage $log doesn't seem to contain such an information. Can someone help me out for solving this?

Comment: FYI - the [tag:sas] tag on [SO] does not refer to this usage of SAS.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll be aware of that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I could think of using which you can include that information:

1. Using **`x-ms-client-request-id`** header in your request. Though not really an ideal purpose of this header but you could include the information about the blob creator in this header and then this information will be available in storage analytics data under `$logs` blob container.
2. Using **`blob metadata`**. This one I would actually recommend. You can actually set some custom attributes in form of name/value pairs when uploading blob. You could very well include the information about the blob creator as blob metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I thought about blob metadata too but the information stored in metadata will disappear after a blob is deleted. If I want to trace which user is creating which blob, it seems that using $logs is the solution because even if a blob is deleted, I still can know who created it before. If you know any better solution, please let me know. I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: If you want you can put this information in a Windows Azure Table as well. With proper design you will have the ability to query as well.